# DuckDB COPY statement clarification

Tags: duckdb

I'm trying to use DuckDB postgres_scanner to export some data to s3.

Let's say I use the ATTACH semantics to attach a postgres database using the following.

```sql
"ATTACH 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres' AS my_db (TYPE postgres, READ_ONLY);"
```

and later perform some query

```sql
COPY (
    SELECT
        d.some_id,
        d.some_other_column
    FROM
        postgres_scan_pushdown($1, 'my_schema', 'my_table') as d
    WHERE
        group_id = $2
) TO 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' (FORMAT 'parquet');
```

Using the python API, I use the following

```py
conn.execute(THE_ABOVE_QUERY, [CONFIG.duck_db_pg_dsn, group_id])
```

I want to replace XXXXXXXXXXXX by some s3 uri which depends on the `group_id`.
Unless I'm mistaken (in that case I apologize in advance) but it looks like it is not possible to  do it with a third placeholder. `$3`.

Could anyone enlighten me on this?

Thank you for your time.